# Android Studio create project screen is changed today

Tags: android-studio

Greetings. 
I am learning java and android development for last two days. I am using android studio version 3.1.3

the welcome screen interface and open project screen that i used yesterday was different.

Today i am seeing a new screen and new way of opening android project.
below are the screen shots.
[image: android studio welcome screen]

when i click on create new project the below screen appears

[image: new create project screen]

please guide me through this.

Comment: Might be an recent update!

Comment: what is the point? and which version you are using?

Comment: android studio 3.1.3.  how to create a new android studio project?

Comment: open any project then try this `File > New > New Project`

Comment: Actually its an IntelliJ Start screen and Create New Project flow. Since Android Studio is based upon open source IntelliJ's IDE code you might be you have triggered something which has caused Android Studio to show IntelliJ's Start Screen and its default flow.

Comment: same window appears.  and when i open an existing project, it shows an error. "three facets cannot be loaded" 1.Java-Gradle(appname) unknown facet type:'java-gradle'       2.Android-Gradle(app)  unknown facet type:'android-gradle'      3.Android(app)  unknown facet type:'android'

Comment: @nitinkumarp is there a way to reset to android studio old start screen.

Comment: Might be some of the plugin were corrupted or removed. Check for the plugins installed in your AS with another AS, if possible. Another way is to reinstall AS.

Comment: i tried reinstalling android studio.but it didnt fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Android Studio folder in the user's folder. Let Android Studio download everything back and the view will become normal.

Answer (score 0):

Going to events on the home screen and clicking 'enable android support' that this fixed my issue, however I did need to re-install all the SDK versions I previously used.